# Correct usage of std::condition_variable to trigger timed execution

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I am trying to execute a piece of code in fixed time intervals. I have something based on naked `pthread` and now I want to do the same using `std::thread`.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

bool running;
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cond;

void timer(){
  while(running) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
    cond.notify_one();
  }
  cond.notify_one();
}

void worker(){
  while(running){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex);
    cond.wait(mlock);
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    //... do something that takes a variable amount of time ...//
  }
}

int main(){
  running = true;
  auto t_work = std::thread(worker);
  auto t_time = std::thread(timer);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000));

  running = false;
  t_time.join();
  t_work.join();
}
```

The `worker` in reality does something that takes a variable amount of time, but it should be scheduled at fixed intervals. It seems to work, but I am pretty new to this, so some things arent clear to me...

- Why do I need a `mutex` at all? I do not really use a condition, but whenever the `timer` sends a signal, the worker should do its job.
- Does the `timer` really need to call `cond.notify_one()` again after the loop? This was taken from the older code and iirc the reasoning is to prevent the `worker` to wait forever, in case the `timer` finishes while the `worker` is still waiting.
- Do I need the `running` flag, or is there a nicer way to `break` out of the loops?

PS: I know that there are other ways to ensure a fixed time interval, and I know that there are some problems with my current approach (eg if `worker` needs more time than the interval used by the `timer`). However, I would like to first understand that piece of code, before changing it too much.

Comment: Why does there need to be a separate timer thread?  Unless you're omitting some important detail, surely the worker thread can simply calculate the next (absolute) time it needs to wake and call sleep_until().  (In that case, the worker thread wouldn't see running==false until the next time interval - but that's already the case.

Comment: BTW, `running` should be `atomic` (or protected by `mutex`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I need a mutex at all? I do not really use a condition, but whenever the timer sends a signal, the worker should do its job.

The reason you need a mutex is that the thread waiting for the condition to be satisfied could be subject to a spurious wakeup. To make sure your thread actually received the notification that the condition is correctly satisfied you need to check that and should do so with a lambda inside the wait call. And to guarantee that the variable is not modified after the spurious wakeup but before you check the variable you need to acquire a mutex such that your thread is the only one that can modify the condition. In your case that means you need to add a means for the worker thread to actually verify that the timer did run out.

> Does the timer really need to call cond.notify_one() again after the loop? This was taken from the older code and iirc the reasoning is to prevent the worker to wait forever, in case the timer finishes while the worker is still waiting.

If you dont call notify after the loop the worker thread will wait indefinitely. So to cleanly exit your program you should actually call notify_all() to make sure every thread waiting for the condition variable wakes up and can terminate cleanly.

> Do I need the running flag, or is there a nicer way to break out of the loops?

A running flag is the cleanest way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I would add the mutex, as it is used here, is also a way to ensure that the condition is effectively being waited upon before firing the notify, or the notify could be lost.

Comment: so the timer should set a flag (ie the condition) that is reset by the worker immediately as it starts its job? I read about spurious wakeups but couldnt come to a conclusion whether it is relevant for this case at all

Comment: If you need to make absolutely sure that the worker only does its job when the timer runs out then yes you need to add a flag that tells the worker the the timer has indeed run out and it was not a spourious wakeup.

Comment: ...still a bit confused. Lets say I would not care about spurious wakeups, thus also dont need a condition (as lambda or whatever) then I also would need no mutex, right? However, triggering the `worker` on spurious wakeups isnt nice and something I want to avoid, thus I do need a condition and access to that condition needs to be protected with a mutex, right?

Comment: A condition variable always needs a mutex. You cannot use one without.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first check the background concepts.

### Critical Section

First of all Mutex is needed to mutually exclude access to a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section). Usually, critical section is considered to be shared resource. E.g. a Queue, Some I/O (e.g. socket) etc. In plain words Mutex is used to guard shared resource agains a [Race Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), which *can* bring a resource into undefined state.

#### Example: Producer / Consumer Problem

A queue should contain some work items to be done. There might be multiple threads which put some work items into the Queue (i.e. produce items => Producer Threads) and multiple threads which consume these items and do smth. useful with them (=> Consumer Threads).

Put and Consume operations modify the Queue (especially its storage and internal representations). Thus when running either put or consume operations we want to exclude other operations from doing the same. This is where Mutex comes into play. In a very basic constellation only **one** thread (no matter producer or consumer) can get access to the Mutex, i.e. **lock it**. There exist some other Higher Level locking primitives to increase throughput dependent on usage scenarios (e.g. [ReaderWriter Locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock))

### Concept of Condition Variables

`condition_variable::notify_one` wakes up one currently waiting thread. At least one thread has to wait on this variable:

- If no threads are waiting on this variable posted event will be lost.
- If there was a waiting thread it will wake up and start running as soon as it can lock the mutex associated with the condition variable. So if the thread which initiated the `notify_one` or `notify_all` call does not give up the mutex lock (e.g. `mutex::unlock()` or `condition_variable::wait()`) woken up thread(s) will not run.

In the `timer()` thread mutex is unlocked after `notify_one()` call, because the scope ends and `guard` object is destroyed (destructor calls implicitly `mutex::unlock()`)

### Problems with this approach

#### Cancellation and Variable Caching

Compilers are allowed to cache values of the variables. Thus setting `running` to `true` might not work, as the values of the variable might be cached. To avoid that, you need to declare `running` as `volatile` or `std::atomic<bool>`.

### `worker` Thread

You point out that `worker` needs to run in some time intervals and it might run for various amounts of time. The `timer` thread **can** only run after `worker` thread finished. Why do you need another thread at that point to measure time? These two threads always run as one linear chunk and have no *critical* section! **Why not just put after the task execution the desired `sleep` call and start running as soon as time elapsed?** As it turns out only `std::cout` is a shared resource. But currently it is used from one thread. Otherwise, you'd need a mutex (without condition variable) to guard writes to `cout` only.

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

std::atomic_bool running = false;

void worker(){
  while(running){
    auto start_point = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    //... do something that takes a variable amount of time ...//

    std::this_thread::sleep_until(start_point+std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

  }
}

int main(){
  running = true;
  auto t_work = std::thread(worker);
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000));

  running = false;
  t_work.join();
}
```

**Note:** With `sleep_until` call in the worker thread the execution is blocked if your task was blocking longer than 1000ms from the `start_point`.

Comment: thanks for the input, but I cannot use your code in the end, because with that the `Hello World` will appear at intervals of `1000` plus whatever time the worker needs to do its actual work. This can be fixed, by measuring the time the worker needs. However, as mentioned in the question I first wanted to understand the code as it is (ie two threads one triggering the other).

Comment: @tobi303: if you want `Hello World` to appear always 1 second, than your code also not going to properly work. It just worked, because your delays were short. What you need is not `sleep_for` but the `sleep_until()` function: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until